# Creditor - Debit + previous row Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with four columns ( id  , Creditor  ,Debit   ,Balance)
I want to work

```
-----------------------------
| id |Creditor|Debit|Balance|
----------------------------
| 1  | 100    |null | null  |
| 2  | 50     |null | null  |
| 3  | null   | 100 | null  |
| 4  | 50     |null | null  |
| 5  | null   | 20  | null  |
| 6  | null   | 10  | null  |
| 7  | null   | 100 | null  |
| 8  | 200    |null | null  |
-----------------------------
```

Creditor - Debit + previous row  Balance

How can I achieve this

Expected Output

```
 -----------------------------
| id |Creditor|Debit|Balance|
----------------------------
| 1  | 100    |null | 100   |
| 2  | 50     |null | 150   |
| 3  | null   | 100 | 50    |
| 4  | 50     |null | 100   |
| 5  | null   | 20  | 80    |
| 6  | null   | 10  | 70    |
| 7  | null   | 100 | -30   |
| 8  | 200    |null | 170   |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: The downvote is because you showed no effort.  Not from me though.

Comment: hint:running total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select (coalesce(sum(creditor) over (order by id), 0) +
        coalesce(sum(debitor) over (order by id), 0)
       ) as balance
```

To set the value, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*
             (coalesce(sum(creditor) over (order by id), 0) +
              coalesce(sum(debitor) over (order by id), 0)
             ) as new_balance
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set balance = new_balance;
```